# Can 0 be an element of a sequence $\{a_k\}$ if $\{a_k\}$ is a sequence of positive real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory

When practicing for my exam real analysis, I came across the following question:

"For each sequence $\{a_k\}$ of positive real numbers, we define $\{p_n\}$ by:
$$ p_1=a_1, \qquad p_{n+1} = p_n a_n, \qquad  \text{i.e. } \space p_n=a_1a_2...a_n. $$
Give an example of a sequence $\{a_k\}$ of positive real numbers such that:
$$ \lim_{k\to \infty}a_k=1 \quad\text{ and} \quad \lim_{n\to \infty}p_n=0$$"

The solution, according to the book, is: $\space a_1=0 \space$ and $\space a_n=1 \space \space \forall n\geq1$.

However, I disagree with this since the question states that the sequence should consist of *positive* real numbers, not of *non-negative* real numbers (in the latter case the answer would have been fine of course). My own answer is

$$ a_n= {n\over n+1}$$

which is better in my opinion. But, I'd like to know whether my book's answer is really wrong, or if one could get away with including 0 in the positive reals?Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah, $0$ is not a positive real number, so the solution given was wrong. Your solution is not just better, it is correct. :)

Comment: (I can only assume the answers in the book were written by someone else, because it also misses completely the point of the question, which is answers like yours.)

Comment: Some say positive but they mean non-negative.. They say strictly positive to mean positive. This world is confusing..

Comment: Something is wrong with your recursion though, since the explicit form does not agree with the recursive form. Did you want to write $p_{n+1} = p_{n} a_{n+1}$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It is actually a booklet with answers to old exam questions written by some expensive tutoring institute on my university. Mostly students who passed this course with very high grades. However, some of the answers leave a lot to be desired...

Comment: Generally speaking, you can always assume, that "positive" means ">0". Anyone, who claims something different, is just abusing the word "positive" or is too lazy to say "nonnegative" instead.

Comment: @Joker123 this is exactly the way as it was stated in the question, which was made by my professor. I doubt it'd be wrong and still included in a final exam. Also, how do the forms not agree with each other?

Comment: It is wrong. If $p_1 = a_1$ and $p_{n+1} = p_n a_n$, then it follows that $p_2 = p_1 a_1 = a_1^2$, which is in contrast to $p_2 = a_2 a_1$.

Comment: @Joker123 sorry, actually you are right. Did not see that until now. Then the question is also formulated wrong.. thanks for notifying me on that.